# Should I save storage or save speed in keeping a history of notes?

Tags: database, database-design

I am creating a note system and want my notes to be editable, but also want them to never be deleted so I'm compromising with keeping a history of the different changes made to them. So I have come up with one idea where each note table looks like this:

```
Note
--------
+id
+content
+author
+timestamp
+edited
```

in this version if edited is anything other than null the note has been edited and points to the `note id` of its ancestor. It is essentially a linked list. I'm not very happy with that though as most notes won't be edited so there's just a bunch of nulls sitting around.

my other idea was to create a table like:

```
Note
-------
+id
+content
+author
+timestamp
```

and also a table like:

```
Edited_Notes
-----------
+id
+note_id
```

then whenever a note is loaded just see if it's been added to `Edited_Notes`. If it has been, then obviously it's been edited. I'm worried that searching through this table every time a note is opened by hundreds of users could be taxing for the database though, especially if I add an ability to see all note history for a single note at once.

I am not a db designer so this is pretty new to me. Would these kinds of transactions even scratch a databases capabilities? Is there a better way to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to avoid empty columns - storage is cheap (too cheap to measure for most systems).

What's usually expensive is developer time. I'd optimize for the most obvious, easy-to-understand solution, that describes your business domain in the cleanest possible way. In my opinion, option 1 does that; option 2 would probably require significant additional queries on most screens.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the solution correctly deep parent child relation could be an issue for a db for even small number of records as you will need to join table by itself several times depending on the change number.

Instead I would recommend a history table separate then note table with the exact same structure with a parent id reference (or you can just use the same note id as a non primary field) to the actual note table. Whenever something changed you should move old data to history table with the parent reference id.